# Unity Firebase Analytics events not showing up

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, analytics, firebase-analytics

I put the Firebase plugin in my Unity application and everything went fine (Android version). I tried with the iOS version but it is not logging the events. I know the events take a few hours to appear but they are not appearing either after 1 day or in debug mode.

For debug mode, I've put the "-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled" argument, just like the tutorial (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events#view_events_in_the_xcode_debug_console).
On another site (https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=pt&utm_id=ad), I realized that there is another argument "-FIRDebugEnabled".
I tried both of them but none logged my events.

Another thing I noticed is that the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file that I downloaded on the Firebase website comes with the variable "IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED" = false. It does not say anything in the tutorial (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/start?hl=pt-br) but I put it true.

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT (LOG):**

```
2017-05-29 12:54:41.638343 brincando[22620:5072036] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023105] Event is not subject to real-time event count daily limit. Marking an event as real-time. Event name, parameters: 
post_score, 
{     
    firebase_screen_id (_si) = -396951154609863799;     
    score = 42;     
    firebase_screen_class (_sc) = UnityDefaultViewController;     
    firebase_realtime (_r) = 1;     
    firebase_debug (_dbg) = 1;     
    firebase_event_origin (_o) = app; 
} 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.640 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023105] Event is not subject to real-time event count daily limit. Marking an event as real-time. Event name, parameters: 
post_score, 
{       
    firebase_screen_id (_si) = -396951154609863799;         
    score = 42;         
    firebase_screen_class (_sc) = UnityDefaultViewController;       
    firebase_realtime (_r) = 1;         
    firebase_debug (_dbg) = 1;      
    firebase_event_origin (_o) = app;   
} 

2017-05-29 12:54:41.646107 brincando[22620:5072192] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS012018] Saving bundle. size (bytes): 415 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.648 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS012018] Saving bundle. size (bytes): 415 

2017-05-29 12:54:41.657411 brincando[22620:5072026] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023116] Bundle added to the upload queue. BundleID, timestamp (ms): 13, 1496073280620 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.658 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023116] Bundle added to the upload queue. BundleID, timestamp (ms): 13, 1496073280620 

2017-05-29 12:54:41.678965 brincando[22620:5072026] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023038] Uploading events. Elapsed time since last successful upload (s): 21.54594898223877 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.679 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023038] Uploading events. Elapsed time since last successful upload (s): 21.54594898223877 

2017-05-29 12:54:41.681181 brincando[22620:5072026] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023039] Measurement data sent to network. Timestamp (ms), data: 1496073281675, <FIRAPBMeasurementBatch: 0x170016af0> 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.681 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023039] Measurement data sent to network. Timestamp (ms), data: 1496073281675, <FIRAPBMeasurementBatch: 0x170016af0> 

2017-05-29 12:54:41.690525 brincando[22620:5072050] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS900000] Uploading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.690 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS900000] Uploading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a 

2017-05-29 12:54:41.747085 brincando[22620:5072192] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901006] Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.747 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901006] Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a 

2017-05-29 12:54:41.849945 brincando[22620:5072050] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023044] Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, 0 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.850 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023044] Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, 0 

2017-05-29 12:54:41.860015 brincando[22620:5072036] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): -0.2379031181335449 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.860 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): -0.2379031181335449 

2017-05-29 12:54:41.860374 brincando[22620:5072036] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): -0.2379031181335449 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.860 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): -0.2379031181335449 

2017-05-29 12:54:41.878356 brincando[22620:5072050] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023024] No data to upload. Upload task will not be scheduled 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.878 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023024] No data to upload. Upload task will not be scheduled 

2017-05-29 12:54:41.878814 brincando[22620:5072050] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled 
2017-05-29 12:54:41.880 brincando[22620] <Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
```

Comment: When you turned on debug mode using that flag, is there anything logged in the Console Log? Can you provide the log and SDK version? You can also use DebugView to verify the traffic at real-time while debugging instead of waiting 2-4 hours.

Comment: Hi adbitx, I tried to use DebugView but nothing appears there.

Comment: From the log, I could see that the event "post_score" was sent correctly to the server. It's strange that you don't see any events in DebugView. I'd recommend to contact Firebase Support directly with your app information.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late answer but I double checked other solution and still had similar issue.

- Make sure all event parameters are sent with a value and not empty.
- Have "-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled" flag enabled
- Have "-FIRDebugEnabled" flag enabled